# PHP search and insert special string

Tags: php

I am inserting a group of strings into my table. This is a sample one,

|=|4|=|3|=|5|=|3|=|Yes|=|No comments .

Sometimes my string may be like

|=|4|=|3|=|5|=|3|=|Yes|=|

For this situation I want to append a string (sorry, no data) to the end of |=|.

Also my string may be like

```
 |=|4|=|3|=|5|=|3|=|Yes|=|
```

That symbol at the end is empty space. In this situation I also want to append this string (sorry, no data) at the end of |=|.

Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: What table do you mean? A database table?

Comment: It’s really hard to get what you’re saying. Maybe you should try to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use susbstr to extract end of string

```
if (substr($string, -3) == '|=|') 
    $string .= '(Sorry no data)';
```

Or with one space character

```
if (substr($string, -1) == ' ') 
        $string .= '(Sorry no data)';
```

You can also achieve same thing with regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

The question is, why do you need to do this? For me, it sounds like the structure of your database is wrong, and you are trying to save *n* variables into 1 field (if I'm right, take a look at *[Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)*, if I'm wrong I missunderstood your question...).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$splitted = explode("|=|", $your_string);
if (count($splitted) < 6)
{
  $your_string .= "Sorry no data";
}
```

If you want to add "Sorry no data" also if the last section is "No comments", change the if to:

```
if (count($splitted) < 6) || $splitted[5] == "No comments")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "|=|4|=|3|=|5|=|3|=|Yes|=|";
$var = explode("|=|",$string);
$pick_last_array = count($var);
$pick_last_array = $pick_last_array-1;
if(trim($var[$pick_last_array])==""){
    $my_last_val =  "Am coming";
}else{
    $my_last_val =  $var[$pick_last_array];
}

echo $my_last_val;
```

This snippet fixed my problem.